# Import Time Data from MATLAB to Excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a machine that has a starting time and end time as shown below:

[image]

I want to read this values in MATLAB and save it to format HH:MM:SS, I'm using this command

```
filename='Name.csv';

W=xlsread(filename, 'B5:B5');
t = datetime(W,'ConvertFrom','excel');
```

I want to get a final array that starts with the start time and add 1 second until it reach the last time like this

```
time=[3:45:13,3:45:14,3:45:15,3:45:16,........,11:25:06]
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you ask and delete this exact question yesterday? I was half way through answering it at the time it disappeared... In future please don't re-submit questions, instead [edit] them with additional details if needed.

Comment: The website decided to close it because it was unclear, so i tried to clarify it and it remained closed, thats why i reposted it

Comment: "The website" doesn't decide anything, community members vote to close questions and you should take on board the reason for closure! Then edit the question to improve it, which can cause it to be re-opened.

Comment: I know that ist the community, and as i said i tried to clarify it by adding more code blocks and expected output but that didnt work, if you have a solution for my question please add it below, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've gotten this far:

```matlab
W = xlsread(filename, 'B5:B5');
t = datetime(W,'ConvertFrom','excel');
P = xlsread(filename, 'B6:B6');
t1 = datetime(P,'ConvertFrom','excel');
```

At that point you have your start time in `t` and your end time in `t1`.

Similar to how you can construct ranges of numbers using the notation `a:b`, you can construct ranges of times using `datetime`s and the `:` operator. Use `start_time:step_size:end_time` to set the step/interval size.

```matlab
time = t:seconds(1):t1
```

Then you can use `datestr()` on the results to convert it to whatever display format you want.